# Magento very slow with config products in cart, EAV: Mage_Eav_Model_Config::getAttribute

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

When I have around 10 config products in my cart and then want to open the cart, magento is so very slow. When I run the profiler this is the bottleneck

EAV: Mage_Eav_Model_Config::getAttribute    23.4532 429804  455,861,784 18,087,936

Can this somehow be improved? I am on a shared hosting server optimized for magento with memcache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use flat tables for your product data (this increases the time it takes to get some of the product data).

To do that go to the backend **system->configuration->catalog**
And in the 'frontend' section set the 'Use Flat Catalog Product' to YES.

Hope this was helpful.

Pesach

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I already have this set to YES :-)